# current mono default garbage collector

Tags: c#, mono, garbage-collection

What is the current GC implementation in mono 4.2?

- According to http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/3.2.0/:

  > Mono now defaults to the SGen Garbage Collector.
- According to http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.4.0/ (preview changelog):

  > The libmono library now defaults to using Mono with SGen, previously, it defaulted to Boehm.

Thanks in advance for clearing this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SGen` is the default collector.

Posted on 14 Jan 2016 by Miguel de Icaza:

[Mono's Cooperative Mode for SGen GC](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2015/Dec-22.html)

> As of today, Mono's Coop engine can either be compiled in by default (by passing --with-cooperative-gc to configure), or by setting the MONO_ENABLE_COOP environment variable to any value.
>
> We have used a precursor of Coop for about 18 months, and now we have a fully productized version of it on Mono master and we are looking for developers to try it out.
>
> We are hoping to enable this by default next year. [1](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2015/Dec-22.html) Astute readers will notice that it still took years of development to make **SGen the default collector in Mono**.